# .net code converting datasources

Tags: .net, dataset, datalist

I have a dataset, How can I use the below code to bind the radchart by using the below Original code?

```
Partial Public Class Chart_Examples_Skinning_Bars_DefaultCS
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim series As New ChartSeries()
            series.Type = ChartSeriesType.Bar
            series.DataXColumn = "XValue"
            series.DataYColumn = "YValue"

            CapacityRadChart.Series.Add(series)

            CapacityRadChart.DataSource = Me.GetDataSource()
            CapacityRadChart.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetDataSource() As List(Of Class1)
        Dim r As New Random()
        Dim source As List(Of Class1) = New List(Of Class1)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 399
            Dim item As New Class1()

            item.XValue = i
            item.YValue = r.[Next](0, 100)

            source.Add(item)
        Next

        Return source
    End Function

End Class
```

I'm doing it in this way, But it is throwing the following error:

> the type of column with "COUNT" is not numeric".

Please could you suggest appropriate code?

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables.Item(0)
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim listdata As new List(Of Double)

Dim list As New List(Of DataRow)(dt.[select]())
    For Each dr  In dt.Rows            
            list.Add(dr.ToLis)
    Next

Dim series As New ChartSeries()
series.Type = ChartSeriesType.Bar
    series.DataXColumn  = "CapacityDelay"
    series.DataYColumn = "COUNT"

    BaselineRadChart.Clear()
    BaselineRadChart.Series.Add(series)

    BaselineRadChart.DataSource = list
    BaselineRadChart.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create a columns in ds.Tables.Item(0)? Do you bind the DataTable directly from database or create the DataTable manually?

If you create it manually, then you may need to declare the DataType for the DataColumn

```
Dim dt As DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("CapacityDelay", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("Count", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
```

Comment: I bind the datatable directly from the database, Is there a way to declare the datacolumns to get them into list?

Comment: If you bind the DataTable directly from database, then the DataColumn Type would actually based on your columns in database. In this case I would suggest you check both your database column and the query, and make sure they are both a numeric format.

Comment: Public Class Class1
 Public Property XValue() As Integer
  Get
   Return m_XValue
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
   m_XValue = value
  End Set
 End Property
 Private m_XValue As Integer
 Public Property YValue() As Integer
  Get
   Return m_YValue
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
   m_YValue = value
  End Set
 End Property
 Private m_YValue As Integer
End Class

Comment: first, should you declare `m_XValue` and `m_YValue` before the propety? Second, you may need to check the value in the datatable and make sure the `COUNT` column are all numeric values

Comment: Your right Nick, My post at May 11 at 16:51 working in that way.